# Normalizr and server-generated IDs

Tags: redux, normalizr

I am using `normalizr` to organize my `redux`-store state.

Let's say that I have normalized todo-list:

```
{
  result: [1, 2],
  entities: {
    todo: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Do something'
      },
      2: {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Second todo'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I would like to implement `addTodo` action. I need to have an id in todo object, so I generate a random one:

```
function todoReducer(state, action) {
   if(action.type == ADD_TODO) {
       const todoId = generateUUID();
       return {
          result: [...state.result, todoId],
          enitities: {
            todos: {
              ...state.entities.todos,
              [todoId]: action.todo
            }
          }
       }
   }
   //...other handlers...
   return state;
}
```

But the problem is that eventually all data will be saved to server and generated id should be replaced with real server-assigned id. Now I merge them like this:

```
//somewhere in reducer...
if(action.type === REPLACE_TODO) {
   // copy todos map, add new entity, remove old
   const todos = {
     ...state.entities.todos
     [action.todo.id]: action.todo
   };
   delete todos[action.oldId];

   // update results array as well
   const result = state.result.filter(id => id !== oldId).concat(action.todo.id);
    // return new state
    return {entities: {todos}, result};
}
```

It seems to be a working solution, but there also a lot of overhead. Do you know any way to simplify this and don't make `REPLACE_TODO` operation?

Comment: Why do you think this is an overhead? What would be an ideal solution in your mind? No matter what, if you optimistically create new todos, eventually when you save, your random id needs to be replaced with the server generated one. For more complex cases you might want to take a look at https://github.com/mattkrick/redux-optimistic-ui

Comment: Exactly, I see overhead in my solution, but I don't know how to resolve it. In my ideal solution I can have several unsaved to server items, but also I should be able to update them easily. (This is why I have normalizr, otherwise I could have just a plain array of items)

Comment: And by easily you mean.... ? By my count you just have to do the replacement and that's it, if you want to feel better about it abstract that into some function, but still, you gotta replace.
Other solution that springs to my mind is trying to make your backend to use (accept) your JS generated ids instead of auto-incrementing some value (would work as long as ids are long and "random" enough). Still, you'd need an extra case for when ids clash and that takes you right back to replacement (although is fired far more sparingly (if ever))